# SQLCMD batch to generate table contents in a CSV - Format issue

Tags: csv, diacritics, sqlcmd, formats

We are currently trying to generate the contents of some tables with SQLCMD in a CSV file, but we get commas instead of accents.

Here is what we have tried:

1/ trying to change output format to -f o:1252
sqlcmd -d environment -U user -P pwd -s; -W -Q   "SELECT  IQID,IQDELETED,...    " 1>VCTRUC.csv -f o:1252

2/ trying to change output format to 65001
sqlcmd -d environment -U user -P pwd -s; -W -Q   "SELECT  IQID,IQDELETED,...    " 1>VCTRUC.csv -f 65001

3/trying to change output format to unicode
sqlcmd -d environment -U user -P pwd -s; -W -Q   "SELECT  IQID,IQDELETED,...    " 1>VCTRUC.csv -u

We always get: "Priv‚e"  instead of "Privée" or "F”renings" instead of "förenings"

Would you know how we can avoid this?

Thanks,